# haskell-stack: main module to load is ambiguous

Tags: haskell, ghci, haskell-stack

I have multiple executables with non-conflicting names. Yet `stack ghci` complains that the main module is ambiguous:

```
$ find . -type f -exec grep -Hi "apple\|banana" {} \; | grep -v work
./ambig.cabal:executable apple
./ambig.cabal:  main-is:             Apple.hs
./ambig.cabal:  ghc-options:         -main-is Apple.apple
./ambig.cabal:executable banana
./ambig.cabal:  main-is:             Banana.hs
./ambig.cabal:  ghc-options:         -main-is Banana.banana
./src/Apple.hs:module Apple (apple) where
./src/Apple.hs:apple :: IO ()
./src/Apple.hs:apple = putStrLn "I am apple"
./src/Banana.hs:module Banana (banana) where
./src/Banana.hs:banana :: IO ()
./src/Banana.hs:banana = putStrLn "I am banana"
$ stack ghci
The main module to load is ambiguous. Candidates are: [...]
$ stack --version
Version 1.5.1, Git revision 600c1f01435a10d127938709556c1682ecfd694e
```

How can I make `stack ghci` load all these non-conflicting modules?

The complete cabal file:

```
$ cat ambig.cabal
name:                ambig
version:             0.1.0.0
build-type:          Simple
cabal-version:       >=1.10

executable apple
  hs-source-dirs:      src
  main-is:             Apple.hs
  ghc-options:         -main-is Apple.apple
  default-language:    Haskell2010
  build-depends:       base >= 4.7 && < 5

executable banana
  hs-source-dirs:      src
  main-is:             Banana.hs
  ghc-options:         -main-is Banana.banana
  default-language:    Haskell2010
  build-depends:       base >= 4.7 && < 5
```

Comment: This is expected behavior because stack does not currently have any magic to parse this out of ghc-options.  I've opened https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/3439 tracking the enhancement.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, if I translate what I did on mine onto your project, you should be able to do either of these to choose the main module:

```
stack ghci --main-is ambig:exe:apple
```

or

```
stack ghci --main-is ambig:exe:banana
```